# Implementing auto loading data from express.js server to Objective-C mobile app

Tags: ios, node.js, objective-c, xcode

I have an app written in Objective-C that needs to autoload some data from a node.js server.

Application 1 sends a message to my server that Application 2 then needs to receive. Application 2 needs to load this message automatically (no refresh buttons). These messages are common data and not Remote Notifications with APN.

I currently use the following:

```
- (void) checkForNewMessages {

   // call the method on a background thread
   dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
       [self->dataParser getMessages:^(NSArray *arr, NSError *error) {
           // If there's an error
           if (error) {
               return;
           }
           // otherwise
           [self->messageArray removeAllObjects];
           self-> messageArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:arr];
           if (self-> messageArray) { // is not nil
               // update UI on the main thread
               dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                   [self->newMessageTimer invalidate];
                   [self tableRefresh];
               });
           }
       }];
   });
}
```

which uses a GET request to pull the messages (controlled by a repeating 10-second timer that invalidates when messages are found).

I figured this would work as it runs in the background - but this has become quite buggy, and relies on a timer - it also often freezes the UI while the request is taking place, even though it should be running in the background.

Essentially, is there a better solution to this type of functionality - or does this seem perfectly valid for a production app.

Comment: Yes, and you rejected it already :) Apple gives you APNS for free. This is a perfect use case for it - you can send a control message to your mobile app telling it to run the HTTP GET request. You could also try to roll your own websockets, although that's a bit of a PITA, really.

Lastly, like it was suggested by @Asperi you are not explicitly requesting backgorund queue in your code

Comment: @zaitsman Thanks! I will look into the possibilities of APN as I already use it for another feature in the app

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT` you allow the system to select a queue which to use and sometimes it can decide to choose main queue, as it is free enough. So in your case it is better approach to specify explicitly that you need background queue, as below

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND, 0), ^{
       [self->dataParser getMessages:^(NSArray *arr, NSError *error) {
       ...
```

Comment: Thanks! I should really have noticed this. I have accepted the answer as this solves my UI freezing while waiting for requests.